# Map a symbol to a specific key

Tags: x11, keyboard-shortcuts, firefox, xkb

I have the following problem: I use the `intl` variant of `gb` keyboard layout, i.e., what you get with:

```
setxkbmap -layout gb -variant intl
```

I use gmail in Firefox, and for some reason, the gmail shortcut to move between tabs in the inbox, which is trigged with the key <kbd>~</kbd>, does not work.

The problem comes from having to press <kbd>~</kbd> and <kbd>Space</kbd> afterwards, so 2 keys, to get the symbol (that is the intl variant, which allows me to write `ñ`, the Spanish letter).

I've tried the `us` layout with the `intl` variant, and in that case the shortcut works, because the `~` symbol can be triggered with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd>.

So, what I want is to have the same behaviour with the `gb` layout. Or, generally, to map <kbd>~</kbd> to any other combination (not involving more than one key).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `xmodmap` to change the mapping of the <kbd>~</kbd> key.

For example on my system (stock US layout) it is configured by default like this:

```
$ xev # then pressing Shift + ~
[..]
KeyRelease event, serial 36, synthetic NO, [..]
root 0xa3, [..]
state 0x11, keycode 49 (keysym 0x7e, asciitilde), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (7e) "~"
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Then I can check out how `keycode 49` is exactly configured:

```
$ xmodmap -pke | grep 'keycode *49'
keycode  49 = grave asciitilde grave asciitilde
```

You can feed an expression like this back to xmodmap, e.g. with something like this:

```
$ xmodmap -e 'keycode  49 = grave asciitilde grave asciitilde'
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. I used
`xmodmap -e 'keycode  51 = numbersign dead_tilde numbersign dead_tilde asciitilde asciitilde bar'`
This way I have `~` with _AltGr_ + _~_, and also with _AltGr_ + _Shift_ + _~_.